# Sonar: method length, conditional operator

Tags: java, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube, checkstyle

I am using Sonarqube 5.0 for Java static code analysis and I want to have a rule to check method length for excessive length and identify the use of the conditional (?) operator. However, I don't see rules for these conditions in the default configuration.

It looks like SonarQube by default has 2 quality profiles, FindBugs and SonarWay.
How can I add these rules to to one or both of these profiles?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this rule:

Methods should not have too many lines
squid : S138